# How to use jProgress bar for ProcessBuilder process?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, process, jprogressbar

I am developing an java application to make a usb drives bootable,by executing CMD command through ProcessBuilder. This takes few seconds, in that i want to show an jprogressbar to increase GUI, i have tried so for, i dont get, Please help me.

This is My Code :

```
private void btn_StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    
{
      String[] command ={"CMD", "/C", "MyCmdCommand"};
      ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );
      probuilder.directory(new File(dri+":\\"));   

      try 
      {
            Process process = probuilder.start();
            process.waitFor();
      }

      catch(IOException e)
      {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
      }
}
```

How i can use JProgressbar in my code and where i have to use?
thank you

Comment: you need to execute cmd command inside a thread and use intermediate progressbar

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: What output does the command give?

Comment: I'm pretty certain you don't want execute the command in the root directory of the device you are trying to format ...

Comment: -1 for posting potentially dangerous code. Moderators have been flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded environment, it is also not thread safe.

This means that any long running or blocking process should never be run within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, as it will prevent it from processing new events, including repaint requests, making the program look like it's hung.

It also means that you should NEVER create or modify the state of ANY UI component from outside the context of the EDT.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

You can use a `Thread` to run the process within, but you will become responsible for ensure that any changes you want to make to the UI are carried out within the context of the EDT manually.  This can become troublesome especially when you want to pass information from the thread to the EDT.

Another solution is to use a `SwingWorker` which provides functionality that can synchronise data between it's background thread and the EDT more easily.  It supports progress notification via the `setProgress` method and `PropertyListener` support as well as the ability to `publish` data from the background thread and `process` within the context of the EDT.  It also has a nice `done` method which lets you know when the background thread has completed, but which is executed within the context of the EDT, for example...

```
public static class FormatWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

    private String drive;

    public FormatWorker(String drive) {
        this.drive = drive;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
    String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "MyCmdCommand"};
    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    probuilder.directory(new File(drive + ":\\"));

    Process process = probuilder.start();
    return process.waitFor();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Now, you might be tempted to pass in the `JProgressBar` to the `SwingWorker` and reset its state within the `done` method, but this does leave it a hanging a little, not knowing when the worker has actually started, sure, you should set the state before you call the worker, but still, it's not the responsibility of the worker to manage the state of the UI

Instead, you could take advantage of the workers `PropertyChangeListener` support, for example...

```
    PropertyChangeListener listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            System.out.println(evt.getPropertyName() + "; " + evt.getNewValue());
            if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {

                SwingWorker.StateValue state = (SwingWorker.StateValue) evt.getNewValue();
                switch (state) {
                    case DONE:
                        try {
                            int exitLevel = ((SwingWorker<Integer, ?>)evt.getSource()).get();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Format command completed with exit level of " + exitLevel);
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(progressBar, ex.getMessage());
                        } finally {
                            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                        }
                        break;
                    case STARTED:
                        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    };
    FormatWorker worker = new FormatWorker("G");
    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    worker.execute();
```

This allows you to decide how you want to respond to the worker, without coupling you to a particular work flow.

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: this answer is far good .just asking did you miss setIndeterminate(true) or it's not need?

Comment: Because the progress bar is passed to the worker, I assumed the caller set it up. Personally, I'd prefer to use a property change listener on worker to monitor the done state and let the caller deal with it all, removing any of the UI responsibility from the worker altogether, but I ran out of time