# Back-up in JAVA takes too much time to execute

Tags: java, swing, file-handling

So, I want to create a backup file for my mysql database.

However when i tried to run the code it takes too much time and still no response.

This is my code:

```java
public void backup() {
    String fileName = "";
    URL url;

    JFileChooser backupFile = new JFileChooser();

    backupFile.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    backupFile.setDialogTitle("Select the Path of Backup");
    backupFile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    backupFile.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    backupFile.setApproveButtonText("Backup Database");
    backupFile.setSize(700, 400);
    backupFile.setLocation(100, 100);

    if (backupFile.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            url = backupFile.getSelectedFile().toURL();
            fileName = url.toString().replaceAll("file:/", "").trim();
            System.out.println(fileName);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Selection");
    }

    try {

        String dbName = AppVars.dbName;
        String dbUser = AppVars.dbUserName;
        String dbPass = AppVars.dbPassword;
        if (!fileName.equals("") && fileName != null) {
            String savePath = fileName + "ssmis.sql";
            String executeCmd = AppVars.xamppUrl + "mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p " + dbPass + " --database " + dbName + " -r " + savePath;

            System.out.println(executeCmd);
            Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            System.out.println("Here");

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup Successful", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup Failed", "Failed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error at Backup " + ex);
    }

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How long takes the MySQL dump command? Probably, that's the reason why it takes so long.

Comment: its been a minute or so, and still not executing the command. My database dont have password, do ineed to put a password?

Comment: Seriously, use a `ProcessBuilder`, it's way more configurable.  Break your command and arguments down in separate `String`s, it solves issues with parameters which have spaces.  Read both the `Process`'s output and error streams to make sure you're not stalling the process. Use a `SwingWorker` to execute the process in so you don't block the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444175/how-to-use-jprogress-bar-for-processbuilder-process/26445184#26445184) for more details

Comment: If you don't have a password you shouldn't pass any to the command line. I think, MySQL could treat it as a blank password when you pass an empty string. Try to run MySQL dump in Java with the same parameters which you used in the command line.

Comment: Execute `executeCmd` on the command line and check how long it takes. A minute is no time for MySql db which has some tables with more than 100'000 rows.

Comment: Hi guys, just fixed it by supplying a password. Thanks though.

Comment: Why? MySQL can back itself up automatically. You certainly shouldn't be writing any kind of Java code for this, or indeed any application code at all.

Comment: I know, but my professor required me to do so. So I dont have any choice.

Comment: OK so define 'too much time'. How long is too long, and what makes you think your Java code has anything to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible to take backup of all the tables individually in mysql, but if it is possible create a multi-threaded application which will take backup from all the tables and they will create backup file individually for each table which probably you can merge from your code. Use [count down latch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) in each thread. Once the processing of threads are done you can merge the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this code in an event listener it will freeze the GUI until the backup completes. You need to run it in a separate thread.